# Make my image carousel loop

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have created the following image carousel with HTML & CSS. It runs on my Wordpress website, on mobile display only. I want it to move constantly and then repeat itself without 'starting over'. I just want it to run in a constant loop.

Is it possible to achieve that with HTML, CSS or jQuery? I prefer not to use plain JS in this case.

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="photobanner">       
        <img src="http://wolfppr.donut.co.il/wp-content/uploads/2018/07/NesherPointer.jpg" alt="נשר">
        <img src="http://wolfppr.donut.co.il/wp-content/uploads/2018/07/2.jpg" alt="Xerox">
        <img src="http://wolfppr.donut.co.il/wp-content/uploads/2018/07/9.jpg" alt="Neutrogena">
        <img src="http://wolfppr.donut.co.il/wp-content/uploads/2018/07/8.jpg" alt="Orbit">
        <img src="http://wolfppr.donut.co.il/wp-content/uploads/2018/07/11.jpg" alt="M & M">
        <img src="http://wolfppr.donut.co.il/wp-content/uploads/2018/07/12.jpg" alt="Mercedes-Benz">            
    </div>
</div>
```

Here's the Image Carousel's CSS:

```
/* Photo Banner */
.container {
    width:100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin: 5px auto;
    background: white;
}

.photobanner {
    height: 120px;
    width: 3000px;
}

.photobanner img {
    height: 120px;
    width: 120px;
}

.photobanner img  {
    -webkit-transition: all 1s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 1s ease;
    -o-transition: all 1s ease;
    -ms-transition: all 1s ease;
    transition: all 1s ease;
}


/*keyframe animations*/
.second {
    -webkit-animation: bannermoves 25s linear infinite;
       -moz-animation: bannermoves 25s linear infinite;
        -ms-animation: bannermoves 25s linear infinite;
         -o-animation: bannermoves 25s linear infinite;
            animation: bannermoves 25s linear infinite;;
}

@keyframes "bannermoves" {
 0% {margin-left: -3000px;}
 100% {margin-left: 200px;}
}

@-moz-keyframes bannermoves {
 0% {margin-left: -3000px;}
 120% {margin-left: 200px;}
}

@-webkit-keyframes "bannermoves" {
 0% {margin-left: -3000px;}
 100% {margin-left: -100px;}
}

@-ms-keyframes "bannermoves" {
 0% {margin-left: -3000px;}
 100% {margin-left: 200px;}

@-o-keyframes "bannermoves" {
 0% {margin-left: -3000px;}
 100% {margin-left: 200px;}
}
```

I know a clumsy solution would be to repreat the links, but I was wondering if there's a way to avoid that and just add some code line or something to the current CSS or HTML.

Comment: try owl carousel

Comment: I think a Javascript solution is your best case scenario, since you'll need to always update the CSS to work correctly if you ever change the image list or any of the images sizes.

Comment: Add a fiddle, please.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you not to create your own carousel but rather use an already existing solution like [Owl.carousel](https://owlcarousel2.github.io/).

Here's an example of a carousel which restarts after the last element, it uses the property [`loop: true`](https://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/docs/api-options.html#loop) to achieve the effect:

```js
var owl = $('.owl-carousel');
owl.owlCarousel({
    items:4,
    loop:true,
    margin:10,
    autoplay:true,
    autoplayTimeout:1000,
    autoplayHoverPause:true
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.3.4/assets/owl.carousel.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.3.4/owl.carousel.min.js"></script>
<div class="photobanner owl-carousel owl-theme">
 <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/350x150" alt="נשר">
 <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/350x150" alt="Xerox">
 <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/350x150" alt="Neutrogena">
 <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/350x150" alt="Orbit">
 <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/350x150" alt="M & M">
 <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/350x150" alt="Mercedes-Benz">
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

This type of carousels are easy. Just add `white-space: nowrap` to .photobanner then use a recursive function. I removed the transitions from CSS. You can still use them tho, but do not use 'margin-left' cause it will create a visual conflict with the marginLeft from jquery animate.

```js
var animateRecursive = function () {

    var photobanner = $(".photobanner");
    
    /**
     * 1. Always get the first child from .photobanner
     */
    var elem = photobanner.children().first();

    /**
     * 2. Append it to .photobanner as last element a cloned version of your 'elem'
     */
    photobanner.append(elem.clone());

    /**
     * 3. Animate it to go to the left and adjust duration
     */
    elem.stop(true, true).animate({
        marginLeft: (-1 * elem.outerWidth()) + 'px'
    }, {
        duration: 500,
        easing: 'linear',
        complete: function () {

            /**
             * 4. Remove the hidden element to keep .photobanner clean
             */
            elem.remove();

            /**
             * 5. Repeat
             */
            animateRecursive();

        }
    });

};

animateRecursive();
```

```css
.container {
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin: 5px auto;
    background: white;
}

.photobanner {
    height: 120px;
    width: 750px;
    overflow: hidden;
    white-space: nowrap;
}

.photobanner img {
    height: 120px;
    width: 120px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
    <div class="photobanner">

        <img src="http://wolfppr.donut.co.il/wp-content/uploads/2018/07/NesherPointer.jpg" alt="נשר">
        <img src="http://wolfppr.donut.co.il/wp-content/uploads/2018/07/2.jpg" alt="Xerox">
        <img src="http://wolfppr.donut.co.il/wp-content/uploads/2018/07/9.jpg" alt="Neutrogena">
        <img src="http://wolfppr.donut.co.il/wp-content/uploads/2018/07/8.jpg" alt="Orbit">
        <img src="http://wolfppr.donut.co.il/wp-content/uploads/2018/07/11.jpg" alt="M & M">
        <img src="http://wolfppr.donut.co.il/wp-content/uploads/2018/07/12.jpg" alt="Mercedes-Benz">

    </div>
</div>
```